# How to find the Taylor series and the radius of convergence of this function $ \frac{2+ (x-1)^2}{8-7x}$

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

> Write down the Taylor series $\displaystyle \sum^\infty_{n=0} a_n(x-x_0)^n$ of the following function at the given base point $x_0$ and determine the radius of convergence.

$$ \frac{2+ (x-1)^2}{8-7x} \ \ \ \ x_0=1$$

The way I approach this is first to substitute $y=(x-1)$ to get $$ \frac{2+y^2}{1-7y}$$ and I can expand this at $y=0$

I did nothing to the numerator, and I only expand the $\dfrac{1}{1-7y}$ at $y=0$, and hence the result is $$ (2+y^2)\sum^\infty_{n=1} (7y)^n$$
Then I determine the radius of convergence of $\displaystyle \sum^\infty_{n=1} (7y)^n$ and the result is $R=\dfrac{1}{7}$.

Thus now I say the Taylor series of function $ \dfrac{2+ (x-1)^2}{8-7x}$ is $$ (2+y^2)\sum^\infty_{n=1} (7y)^n= (2+(x-1)^2)\sum^\infty_{n=1} (7(x-1))^n$$

and the radius of convergence is just $\dfrac{1}{7}$ which means that $|x-1|<\dfrac{1}{7}$ this series converges

1. The reason I think my solution might be wrong:

The thing I'm not sure about is that I only expand $\dfrac{1}{1-7y}$ and I did nothing to $2+y^2$. Then I get a series which is $\displaystyle (2+y^2)\sum^\infty_{n=1} (7y)^n$, but I didn't make this into a form like $\displaystyle\sum a_n y^n$ instead, I have an $(2+y^2)$ before the series $\displaystyle\sum a_n y^n$.

---

2. The reason I think my solution might be right:

However, if I indeed make $(2+y^2)$ go into the series and let it become $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1} (2+y^2)(7y)^n$ since it doesn't relate to $n$, by the ratio test or square root test, it doesn't make any change to the radius of the convergence of the series. And if I multiply out $(2+y^2)(7y)^n$, I can get something like $a_0+a_1y+a_2y^2+\cdots+a_ny^n=\displaystyle \sum^\infty_{n=0}a_ny^n$. And I do the convergence test to $a_n$, I think since the series doesn't change $\lim \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ will still give me $\dfrac{1}{7}$. Thus $\displaystyle (2+y^2)\sum^\infty_{n=0} (7y)^n$ is enough to show everything

Anyway, is my solution right or wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You are correct that your Taylor series is not in the right form. $$(2+y^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (7y)^n=\sum_{n} 2\cdot 7^ny^n+\sum_{n} 7^ny^{n+2}=\sum_{n}a_ny^n$$

Where $a_0=2, a_1=2\cdot 7=14,$ and $a_n=7^{n-2}+2\cdot 7^n$ when $n\geq 1.$